# PHP GD - How to apply anti-alias on line's thickness (diagonal line)

Tags: php, gd

I have an image below created with PHP GD (Graphics Draw), the image is created with imagepng().

[image: not smooth line]

My problem is that the diagonal lines are not smooth. My senior told me to try to look up anti-alias and when I look up [imageantialias()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php) function in the docs, it says that thickness are not supported:

> Thickness and styled are not supported.

But just to be sure I still try to use it:

```
imagesetthickness($img, 3); 
imageline($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, 2); 
imageline($img, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, 2); 
imageline($img, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4, 2); 
imageline($img, $x4, $y4, $x5, $y5, 2); 
imageline($img, $x5, $y5, $x6, $y6, 2); 
imageline($img, $x6, $y6, $x7, $y7, 2); 
    
imageantialias($img, true);
```

and it still doesn't work... So is there a way to make the diagonal lines smooth?

Comment: Perhaps creating a separate GD instance, drawing the lines at 300% scale, then use `imagecopyresampled` to downscale it onto the original image would give result the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible as per the [docs of imageantialias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php)

> Thickness and styled are not supported.